# Benchmarking code in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, performance-testing

Does anyone have any tips or links to libraries to help with benchmarking applications in AS3? I'm (hopefully) looking for something along the lines of [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/) but for Flash and AIR. Any suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 4):

A quick way to measure code execution time that I often times use is:

```
var start_time:int = getTimer();

someComplexCode();

trace("execution time: ", getTimer()-start_time);
```

This will give you a number in milliseconds.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really meant for benchmarking, but [Adobe Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/) is a fantastic profiler/performance tester. I've been using it for everything from SWFs for the web to Adobe AIR apps to mobile AIR apps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this: [Performance Test](http://gskinner.com/blog/assets/PerformanceTest.zip). Also, I found some good information [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS4bebcd66a74275c3-315cd077124319488fd-7fff.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a benchmarking method quite easily:

```
function test(process:Function, repeat:int = 10):void
{
    var time:Number = getTimer();
    while(--repeat >= 0) process();
    trace(getTimer() - time);
}
```

Used like so:

```
// See how long it takes to create 50,000 Sprites and
// add them to the DisplayList.
test(function()
{
    var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
    addChild(sprite);

}, 50000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [lostPixels' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15767026/1762224), I created a function that is similar to Python's [`timeit()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) function. The function repeats the callback function for the number of iterations specified and returns the fastest execution time. The default is 1,000,000 iterations.

The following Test program ran in about *391ms* on my machine. Without the `trace()` statements, the test takes less than *1ms* to execute.

***TimeIt.as***

```
package {
  public class TimeIt {
    import flash.utils.getTimer;

    public static function timeIt(callback:Function, maxIterations:uint=1000000):int {
      var start_time:int, duration:int, fastest_time:int = int.MAX_VALUE;
      for (var i:int = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
        start_time = getTimer();
        callback();
        duration = getTimer() - start_time;
        if (duration < fastest_time) fastest_time = duration
      }
      return fastest_time;
    }
  }
}
```

***Test.as***

```
package {
  public class Test {
    public function Test() {
      trace('Fastest Time:', TimeIt.timeIt(test, 10),'ms');
    }

    public function test():void {
      var k:int, m:int = 100;
      for (var i:int = 0; i < m; i++) {
        for (var j:int = 0; j < m; j++) {
          k = m * i + j;
          trace(k);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

***Main.mxml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    initialize="init(event)">
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            protected function init(event:Event):void {
                new Test();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```